# RoundedTextInput in Kivy drawing RoundedRectangle over TextInput

Tags: python, windows, kivy

I'm trying to make an app using Kivy in Python and have gotten stuck as my TextInput isn't working properly, the TextInput field draws under the RoundedRectangle and I can't figure out why with my limited knowledge of Kivy.

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing: 10
    padding: 10
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2)  
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    RoundedText:
        id: nameInput
        hint_text: 'Enter Name'

    RoundedText:
        id: ageInput
        hint_text: 'Enter Age'

    RoundedText:
        id: subjectInput
        hint_text: 'Enter Subject'

    RoundedText:
        id: scoreInput
        hint_text: 'Enter Score'

    RoundedButton:
        text: 'Add Data'
        on_press: app.addData(root)

    RoundedButton:
        text: 'Add to Database'
        on_press: app.addToDb(root)

<RoundedText@TextInput>:
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 200, 50

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [20]

    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)  
    hint_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.7 
    foreground_color: 1, 1, 1, 1  

    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1 
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [20]

<RoundedButton@Button>:
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0) 
    background_normal: ''  
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
    size: 200, 50  
    size_hint: None, None  

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.6, 1, 1) if self.state == 'normal' else (0, 0.5, 0.8, 1) 
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.center_x - self.width / 2, self.center_y - self.height / 2
            radius: [20]
```

I've changing the canvas.before and canvas.after also used canvas by itself and none of it has actually put the RoundedRectangle behind the text input, any help is appreaciated

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a widget, it inherits the canvas instructions from its base class. So your `RoundedText` gets the canvas instructions from the `TextInput` along with the canvas instructions that you have defined. Sometimes it is simpler just to replace all the canvas instructions with what you want. To do that, you start the kivy rule with a `-` (See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#redefining-a-widget-s-style)). Here is a modified version of your `RoundText` rule that I think does what you want:

```
<-RoundedText@TextInput>:
    background_color: (.2, .2, .2, 1)  # using a background color with alpha of 0 makes it invisible
    hint_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.7 
    foreground_color: 1, 1, 1, 1  
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 200, 50
    
    canvas.before:
        # this is the background
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [20]
                
        # This is the cursor
        Color:
            rgba:
                (self.cursor_color
                if self.focus and not self._cursor_blink
                and int(self.x + self.padding[0]) <= self._cursor_visual_pos[0] <= int(self.x + self.width - self.padding[2])
                else (0, 0, 0, 0))
        Rectangle:
            pos: self._cursor_visual_pos
            size: root.cursor_width, -self._cursor_visual_height
            
        # This sets the text color
        Color:
            rgba: self.disabled_foreground_color if self.disabled else (self.hint_text_color if not self.text else self.foreground_color)
```